# Android: avoid multiple instances of the same activity?

Tags: android

My app is capable of opening files from the Dropbox.  Currently, the following scenario occurs

1. Open the Dropbox app from app drawer
2. Select a file in Dropbox, launch with my app
3. My app opens and displays the selected file
4. Hit home button.
5. Select my app from app drawer
6. My app opens and displays with no file displayed
7. Hit back, the empty version of my app closes and the version my app displaying the Dropbox file is now running

If my app was launched from Dropbox, hitting home and launching my app from the app drawer should restore the running Activity (the one displaying the Dropbox file).  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `singleTask` property. It may be set in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="my.activity.package.MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

More about those flags:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: `singleTop` or `singleTask` ?